# Badge "multiplier" a little bit misaligned on the profile page

Tags: bug, badges, design, profile-page

[image]

Well, you can see it for yourself. The badge multiplier is a bit misaligned. Can you fix this please? (I *know* it's kinda a minor issue but it's bugging me and it's somehow off)

If it helps, I'm using Chrome version 44.0.2403.125 m. (Also repro'ed on FireFox 39.0 and [FireFox 24.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UVqb.jpg))

---

<sub>For no good reason, that's a screenie from [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose)'s profile page.</sub>

Comment: Repro'd on Ubuntu 14.04 on Firefox 39.0 and Chrome 44.0.2403.125 x64.

Comment: Also repro'd it on Chrome 43 & Opera under Windows 8.1

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M AHHH - I was looking in the wrong place! I can repro! +1 :).. I kind of ignored your scrrenshot! :/

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Here is a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vqlgr.jpg) from Safari 8 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Probably having more than one of those rare badges is so rare, they didn't have chance to test this. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upon doing the *inspect element* on Kevin Montrose's profile Badges count, I see the relevant HTML code as:

```
<li>
        <a href="/help/badges/37/populist?userid=130213" title="gold badge: Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x" class="badge"><span class="badge1"></span>&nbsp;Populist</a>
            × <span class="earned-count">2</span>
        <span class="badge-date">aug 29 '12</span>
</li>
```

Whereas, when I compare that to [Anna Lear's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/anna-lear) profile I see:

```
<li>
    <a href="/help/badges/59/support?userid=155160" title="gold badge: Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the support tag" class="badge-tag"><span class="badge1"></span>&nbsp;support</a>
    <span class="badge-date">apr 3 '13</span>
</li>
```

I do not see the `× <span class="earned-count">n</span>` element for the three of the currently listed badges under the Gold section. I also checked if it has something to do with "Populist" badge. Anna does have a [Populist (x 2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/populist?userid=155160) badge on her profile. So, that's not the case here.

I did a check on few other top ranked users profile ([Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded), and few others) where the *count* was not shown for the badges. But then, I found [Monica Cellio's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) where the badge count is displayed next to it. I can't tell what kinda algorithm is used here. It's a mystery for sure.

As for the **mis-alignment** goes, yes OP is correct. It ***can be fixed*** by adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the below CSS code.

```
.badges-content .rarest .badges-list .badge, .badges-content .rarest .badges-list .badge-tag {
    max-width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

-OR-

```
body.user-page #content * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

There might be another better way to achieve this as CSS can do many wonders to a design. But that's what I can think as of now. Although adding vertical-align: middle; has solved the alignment issue but it might have other drawing implications somewhere else. I didn't experiment much. I would leave this to SE's UI/UX team for further experiment.

I am on MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite Ver. 10.10.4. I can reproduce this **alignment error** in my Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)) and Firefox (Version 39.0).

The below is the screenshot of **Safari** Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12). This is a default view i.e. *no changes* made to the CSS code. The alignment **works perfectly** here.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. ;)

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M The alignment is perfect on Safari Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12) on Mac OS X Yosemite Ver. 10.10.2

Comment: . . . which is one the biggest mysteries of IT industry. Seriously, how in the world is it aligned well on **SAFARI**?!

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M See my updated answer. I added CSS code to fix the issue.

Comment: It seems that in your fix, the date (`float:right`) is now misaligned.

Comment: @Bergi I just tried in Chrome the first option and vertical-align works. Could you upload a screenshot at imgur and link here. Also, if you notice I did put a note about "Although adding vertical-align: middle; has solved the alignment issue but it might have other drawing implications somewhere else. I didn't experiment much. I would leave this to SE's UI/UX team for further experiment"

Comment: @HackerKarma: It's visible in your own screen shot already :-) The date (a floating block) is top-aligned, higher than the multiplier text. Try [my solution from here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300948/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi that's the original screenshot from Safari without the "vertical-alignment" CSS code change. You can take a look if you have a Safari browser.

Comment: @HackerKarma: Ah, right. Yeah, that's exactly how it looks in the other browsers with the `vertical-alignment` applied for the `.badge`. Just saying that the date is (has always been) misaligned, and that it should be on line with the multiplier.

Comment: @Bergi I guess someone may have to post a feature-request for "date misalignment" too