# What algorithm is used to display the Badges multipliers on the user profile?

Tags: discussion, badges, design, profile-page

Earlier today I answered a question about the [**badge multiplier mis-alignment**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261902/badge-multiplier-a-little-bit-misaligned-on-the-profile-page) on the user profile page. While debugging the answer for that question, I went through few of the top ranked users profile pages such as [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded), etc. where the *badge count* (x multiplier) was *not* shown for the top 3 Gold badges they have earned. But then, upon looking [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) and [Monica Cellio's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) profile, I noticed the badge count is displayed next to some of their top 3 Gold badges.

Here, I would like to give an example of Shog9 and Monica Cellio's profile page for the comparison purpose. Pay attention to the list of ***Rarest*** badges under the Gold Badges section.

Here is [**Shog9**'s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) Badges section screenshot:

> [image]

and, here is [**Monica Cellio**'s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) Badges section screenshot:

> [image]

I would like to know what kinda algorithm is used while determining when to display or not to display the badge count multiplier. Can anyone please explain this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiplier is only shown when the badge has been awarded multiple times, and that's really all there is to it.

In a majority of the cases in your examples, the featured badges can only ever be awarded once *anyway*, so there was never a chance of them being awarded multiple times, but this holds true even for multiple-award badges only received once:

[image: my "rarest" gold badges]