# Where did my newly posted question go?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I <s>just</s> posted [What algorithm is used to display the Badges multipliers on the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261932/what-algorithm-is-used-to-display-the-badges-multipliers-on-the-user-profile) question and it was shown there on the main page i.e. "newest" section and "recently active" section.

But, few minutes later my post got an answer that was totally irrelevant to what I asked for. So, I  downvoted it and flagged it as "not an answer". I guess some other user also found that answer was wrong so he/she also downvoted it.

Here is the screenshot of my flag summary page:

> [image]

My question does not have any ***downvotes*** or **on hold** status, but it's been taken out from the "newest" or "recently active" section. The only downvotes (-2) here are for the wrong answer given by newly registered user "[Theodore Belleabs Theosop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/300709/theodore-belleabs-theosop)". Later, the answer was *deleted* by moderator. The only proof I have is the above screenshot. My question appeared at both the places after deleting the user's answer.

As per the [threshold limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769) a score of -8 and lower cause the question to not be displayed in question lists. But, here my question has no negative score. So, how did it got disappeared? Can anyone please explain this.

Here is a screenshot of my "newest" page:

> [image]

Here is a screenshot of my "recently active" page:

> [image]

**P.S.**

I just noticed the exact same behavior on "[We should always be able to include explanation with moderator flags...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262134/we-should-always-be-able-to-include-explanation-with-moderator-flags-even-if-th)" question just posted few minutes back. The post got disappeared from the *newest* and *recently active* page as soon as the answer on that post got first down-vote. I even posted my comment there. Later, upon receiving an up-vote (0 score i.e. no negative vote) the post reappeared at both the places.

There is something going on here for sure. It's also confirmed (read comment below) by [Tim Stone](https://stackapps.com/users/4746/tim-stone) (♦ moderator of Stack Apps). I <s>don't</s> know how to reproduce this. I just witness it on my own question:"[What is the correct count of all Stack Exchange Network sites?...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262146/what-is-the-correct-count-of-all-stack-exchange-network-sites-is-it-154-or-149)" where I got down-vote for my answer and the post got disappear. I deleted my answer but if you have enough rep. you will see it. Can anyone from SE team please investigate this issue.

Comment: In case it's http://shouldiblamecaching.com/, I can independently confirm that it's randomly missing right now.

Comment: @TimStone I just added two screenshots for the proof. So, did you see my post?

Comment: I did, and then it disappeared.

Comment: But, cache is on my end right? not at your or other users right? How come you saw only once

Comment: No, it's definitely a bug for everyone, I just commented to confirm it is an issue in case it "fixes" itself.

Comment: oh wait... you have posted an answer to my post. I see it after clicking the direct URL of my vanished post... So, after posting an answer the post should appear on the "recently active" page right? This is VERY strange bug. Something is terribly wrong here... I will look into your answer as soon as I get this resolved.

Comment: I see it on newest tab but I'm not using the new nav. Wonder if this issue was only for new nav?

Comment: @Dronehinge Thanks. Then it means this has something to do with new-nav.

Comment: Ok... At 11.04pm CST my missing post is finally appeared on the newest and recently active page.

Comment: The lesson appears to be: don't use new navigation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it's been a bug *everywhere* since a year or so, due to a dumb default value (spoiler: 0) for the min answer score (== sum of all answer scores on a question)

This was fixed in the last build (build rev `2015.8.6.3641` on MSE/MSO, `2015.8.6.2781` on sites) for all sites (not just new-nav enabled ones).

Comment: Last build? when was this deployed? you mean to say rev "2015.8.6.3641"?  Could you please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I like what you said in the comment to @NormalHuman below my post. I think it would be great if you could add that to your answer for two things: 1) that's the real reason why was this issue exist and 2) it will show up in search results as comments are not searchable.

Comment: yeah, sorry for being sloppy @HackerKarma